# Python - How do I get the process name of the focused window on Ubuntu?(not the window title)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am writing a script recording how many time I spend on each applications every day.
But I don't know how to get the process I am focusing on and its name.
How can I achieve that?
By the way, I see a lot of ways to get the focused window ID.
Can I use it to get the process name?

Comment: so, it's not really a dup, but for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151407/how-to-get-an-x11-window-from-a-process-id and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041532/getting-pid-and-details-for-topmost-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to use [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) where you want to look up [events](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/).

As an example of usage, I used it to create [kitt](https://github.com/guyzmo/kitt) that handles multitouch gesture stuff on Xorg:

- https://github.com/guyzmo/kitt/blob/master/kitt/plugin_xlib.py

here's the code:

```
from Xlib import X, XK, protocol, display, Xcursorfont
from Xlib.ext import xtest
from Xlib.protocol import request

disp = display.Display()

root = disp.screen().root
pointer_info = request.QueryPointer(display = disp.display,
                                    window = root)
root_xpos, root_ypos = (pointer_info._data['root_x'], pointer_info._data['root_y'])
targetwindow = disp.get_input_focus().focus
```

now once you got the `targetwindow`, on which you can get many things like the id.

Now, to get back to your question "how to get the PID of a window", the answer is that it's 
not really possible, because of [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2042371/1290438),
though there are hacks around that.

The idea behind those hacks is that, though you can't tell what *exact* process (and thus its PID) is running the window, you can know its full name. You can't because Xorg is a client-server system where the application can be a process running on a distant machine that can have the same PID as a local process. But, the idea of the hack is to get the full name of the program (using the `WM_CLASS` property) and guess the PID from the process' list.

The most obvious ones, using `xprop`

```
ps -o pid,comm,args $(xprop -id $(xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}") -f _NET_WM_PID 0c " \$0\\n" _NET_WM_PID | awk "{print \$2}")
```

or

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) _NET_WM_NAME WM_CLASS
```

or even using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

But, back to the Xlib we're using, I'm pretty sure it can be achieved using a code
like [that one](https://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/source/browse/tools/xpropwatch.py?r=2140),
though I don't have a ready made code for that, but you'll have to check there for the `WM_CLASS` property. Which will contain the name of the application as shown in the process list... tada \o/

HTH