# X11: list top level windows

Tags: window, x11, ewmh, icccm

So far I've found two approaches:

1. For each root window (default screen, specific screen, all screens, etc), list each immediate child. Search each immediate child recursively for a window with the `WM_STATE` property; that window becomes the top-level application window of the immediate child and all recursion can stop. If no window within the hierarchy of the immediate child has the `WM_STATE` property, assume the immediate child is itself the top-level application window.

   - Use `xcb_get_property`, and `xcb_query_tree` (which despite the name lists only immediate children).
   - This is what *xlsclients* uses, via XCB (same algorithm as above, more or less).
   - **Requirements**: requires ICCCM (window manager) support for `WM_STATE`.
2. For each root window (default screen, specific screen, all screens, etc), get "_NET_CLIENT_LIST" property which lists all the top-level application windows managed by the window manager.

   - Use `xcb_get_property`.
   - This is what *wmctrl* uses, via Xlib.
   - Requires the window manager to maintain the list. [Some windows seem to escape the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211242).
   - **Requirements**: EWMH (window manager) support for `_NET_CLIENT_LIST` or `_WIN_CLIENT_LIST` (I have no idea what the second one is; I can't find any documentation).

Questions:

1. Are there any other approaches? Are there any approaches that do not depend on external mechanisms such as ICCCM or EWMH?
2. Which approach is the most resilient?

   1. EWMH. I've found some reports (linked above) that certain applications don't become listed in `_NET_CLIENT_LIST`. Why is this?
   2. ICCCM. This approach seems more flexible, but won't otherwise windowless applications be matched by assuming the immediate child of hierarchies lacking `WM_STATE` is a top-level application window? Even worse, won't it break horribly under [virtual root windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_window#Virtual_root_window)? For example, the virtual root window becomes the only immediate child, and recursion will stop on the first application window with `WM_STATE`; only a single window will be matched. Against this eventuality, `xlsclients` does not include any checks for virtual root windows... so why does it work with GNOME (which uses virtual root windows)?

Comment: No, AFAIK there are no other mechanisms. A window manager doesn't tell you whether it reparents or not (in a standardized way), so without some spec like ICCCM or EWMH, you cannot know. And while uncomfortable for you, keeping paradigmes out of the X11 core specification was a conscious decision. Given that core X tools use these mechanisms for some decades now, I think they're safe to use.