# X11: Get the list of main windows using xcb

Tags: x11, xcb

I'm trying to get the list of the main windows of already launched X applications, with a C program using xcb library. It seems these windows are the "top-level windows" according to this question: [X11: list top level windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359063/x11-list-top-level-windows)

So my program asks Openbox window manager to give the list of these windows, and then asks the name of each window, but it doesn't work. I'm using EWMH atoms, and I have read that Openbox is EWMH compliant.

Edit: And when I run the console command: `xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST`, it gives the identifier of a few windows. So it seems Openbox support this atom. I looked at the code of `xprop`, but it is written with Xlib, and I need to use xcb because of multithreading support.

When My program get a reply from Openbox, the length of the reply is 0.

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

xcb_atom_t getatom(xcb_connection_t* c, char *atom_name)
{
    xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t atom_cookie;
    xcb_atom_t atom;
    xcb_intern_atom_reply_t *rep;

    atom_cookie = xcb_intern_atom(c, 0, strlen(atom_name), atom_name);
    rep = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, atom_cookie, NULL);
    if (NULL != rep)
    {
        atom = rep->atom;
        free(rep);
        printf("\natom: %ld",atom);
        fflush(stdout);
        return atom;
    }
    printf("\nError getting atom.\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
  xcb_generic_error_t *e;
  int i,j,k;

  xcb_connection_t* c = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
  xcb_atom_t net_client_list = getatom(c,"_NET_CLIENT_LIST");
  xcb_atom_t net_wm_visible_name = getatom(c,"_NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME");

  xcb_screen_t* screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(c)).data;

  xcb_get_property_cookie_t prop_cookie_list,prop_cookie;
  xcb_get_property_reply_t *reply_prop_list,*reply_prop;

  prop_cookie_list = xcb_get_property(c, 0, screen->root, net_client_list, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, 0);
  reply_prop_list = xcb_get_property_reply(c, prop_cookie_list, &e);
  if(e) {
    printf("\nError: %d",e->error_code);
    free(e);
  }
  if(reply_prop_list) {
    int value_len = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply_prop_list);
    printf("\nvalue_len: %d",value_len);
    if(value_len) {
      xcb_window_t* win = xcb_get_property_value(reply_prop_list);
      for(i=0; i<value_len; i++) {
        prop_cookie = xcb_get_property(c, 0, win[i], net_wm_visible_name, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, 0);
        reply_prop = xcb_get_property_reply(c, prop_cookie, &e);
        if(e) {
          printf("\nError: %d",e->error_code);
          free(e);
        }
        if(reply_prop) {
          int value_len2 = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply_prop);
          printf("\nvalue_len2: %d",value_len2);
          if(value_len2) {
            char* name = xcb_get_property_value(reply_prop);
            printf("\nName: %s",name);
            fflush(stdout);
          }
          free(reply_prop);
        }
      }
    }
    free(reply_prop_list);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the problem, in the examples I have read on internet, the field `long_length` of `xcb_get_property()` was set to `0`, but it seems that to get a consistant reply, the field must have a value higher or equal to the number of 32 bits words that the reply will have. So I have chosen `100` for my test, but if there is more than 100 top-level windows in the children tree of the specified root window, then the reply will be truncated to the 100 first windows.

I also had to divide `value_len` by `4` to get the number of elements in the reply, because `value_len` is in bytes, and the reply value is an array of xcb_window_t elements, each beiing 4 bytes long.

To get the name of each top-level window, I have chosen to set to `1000` the field `long_length` of `xcb_get_property()`, in order to be sure to have the complete name. But it seems that in the reply, the true size of the string is allocated without the final `\0` character, so I had to allocate a memory block of length `value_len2 + 1`, and then use `strncpy()` to copy the string to this new location. And finally, add the final `\0` character.

Here is the correct code to get the property:

```
  prop_cookie_list = xcb_get_property(c, 0, screen->root, net_client_list, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, 100);
  reply_prop_list = xcb_get_property_reply(c, prop_cookie_list, &e);
  if(e) {
    printf("\nError: %d",e->error_code);
    free(e);
  }
  if(reply_prop_list) {
    int value_len = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply_prop_list);
    printf("\nvalue_len: %d",value_len);
    if(value_len) {
      xcb_window_t* win = xcb_get_property_value(reply_prop_list);
      for(i=0; i<value_len/4; i++) {
        printf("\n--------------------------------\nwin id: %d",win[i]);
        prop_cookie = xcb_get_property(c, 0, win[i], net_wm_visible_name, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, 1000);
        reply_prop = xcb_get_property_reply(c, prop_cookie, &e);
        if(e) {
          printf("\nError: %d",e->error_code);
          free(e);
        }
        if(reply_prop) {
          int value_len2 = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply_prop);
          printf("\nvalue_len2: %d",value_len2);
          if(value_len2) {
            char* name = malloc(value_len2+1);
            strncpy(name,xcb_get_property_value(reply_prop),value_len2);
            name[value_len2] = '\0';
            printf("\nName: %s",name);
            fflush(stdout);
            free(name);
          }
          free(reply_prop);
        }
      }
    }
    free(reply_prop_list);
  }
```

Comment: You only need to allocate a string for the window name if you want it to persist after you `free()` the reply returned by `xcb_get_property_reply()`. Otherwise, you can just print it out directly from the pointer that `xcb_get_property_value()` returns (cast it from `void*` to `char*`)!